# Matrix Row size comparison with Vector item?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have matrix [m x n] and vector [m], and I want to compare each row with the corresponding vector number, is there way to do this vectorized method ?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Check if the corresponding vector number equals the entry in the matrix? or is bigger than, or smaller than, or some other comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `bsxfun`:

```
% example data
M = rand(5, 3);
V = rand(5,1);

% for equality (==) : 
bsxfun(@eq, V, M);

% for greater-than (>) : 
bsxfun(@gt, V, M);

% for greater-than-or-equals (>=) : 
bsxfun(@ge, V, M);
```

etc. The list of available functions is listed in `help bsxfun`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `intersect` function to compare if any vector members are in the matrix.
Then save those memebers into a new vector if that's helpful to you.

```
x = [mxn]
y = [m]
z=intersect(x,y)
```

e.g.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,]
y = [5,6,2]
z = intersect(x,y)
```

will result in

```
z = [2,5]
```

Improved answer would be:-

```
[z,ix,iy] = intersect(x,y)
```

where ix, iy gives you the row index of y element's existence in X.

Comment: suppose you have vector v = [10 ; 1;3 4;5], when you do v == 10 for example you get ans = [1;0;0;0];
but here I have matrix and I want to compare each row with column's item in same concept

Comment: Sorry for the late comeback. I am glad you have gotten the answer though. :)